# To reset the dynamically added field values

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

My component has 2 fields called `employee`(dropdown) and `EmployeeId`, I am adding these 2 field values dynamically as shown in below pic:

[image]

when i select the particular Employee(ex Employee2)to **edit**, I will get that Employee(Employee2) values back to the input fields like this:

[image]

> Here i am facing 2 issues:

- When i change the selected  Employee(Ex Employee2) value, It is reflecting before clicking **add** button:

[image]

**It should reflect only after clicking add button**

- when the user mistakely select the particular Employee to **edit** but he don't want to **edit** the Employee, Then the selected Employee(Ex Employee 2) must removed from the input fields on clicking the `Clear` button, I tried to remove the Employe from the i/p field but i am removing along with the details like this:
  [image]

It should remove like this:

[image]

**[Stackblitz DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-issue-xgzfr4?file=app/demo/demo.component.ts)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this code :

```
  addFieldValue() {
    if(this.newAttribute.employee && this.newAttribute.id){
      const index = this.fieldArray.findIndex((item) => this.newAttribute.employee === item.employee);
      if (index<0) {
        this.fieldArray.push(this.newAttribute)
      }else{
        this.fieldArray[index] = this.newAttribute
      }
    }

    this.newAttribute = {};
  }          

  editFieldValue(index) {
     this.newAttribute = {...this.fieldArray[index]};
  }
```

**But** you can't push 2 employee_1

If you want to push multiple employees with the same name, you can try:

```
  editedField:number;

  addFieldValue() {
    if(this.newAttribute.employee && this.newAttribute.id){
      if (this.editedField == undefined) {
        this.fieldArray.push(this.newAttribute)
      }else{
        this.fieldArray[this.editedField] = this.newAttribute;
        this.editedField = undefined;
      }
    }

    this.newAttribute = {};
  }          

  editFieldValue(index) {
     this.editedField = index;
     this.newAttribute = {...this.fieldArray[index]};
  }
```

Comment: any solution to push duplicates??

Comment: @Prashanth The problem is that you need a reference in the list of the item you want to edit. I have used the name. But you can try something else. See my next edit.

Comment: Thanks for your response@Wandrille

Comment: @Prashanth Your question was well described.